# route traffic to github through specific network interface

Tags: networking, routing, git, github

My Situation;
My computer is in this stupid cooperate network of the company i work for. They have alot of policies and stuff, so its not possible to make a tunnel/connect to github.com through the normal network interface. But because we still need to be able to do whatever we want, we have wireless, that is open. Smart, eeeh?! The good part; my machine has two interface; wired and wireless.

What I want;
I want to route all traffic to github.com through my wireless connection. Nothing more than this, so that I can go and do a "git fetch origin" or similar.

What I found out, tried and failed;
My first thought was "ah yeah, lets just add a route!", so thats what I did! But because I cant add a domain, I did a nslookup to find the IP of github, which is 207.97.227.243, so I added a rule like so; "ip route add 207.97.227.240/28 dev wlan0", but if I want to do a "git fetch origin", it says "the remote end hung up unexpectedly". (I configured 'origin' like so; "git remote add origin git@github.com/myusername/mygit.git")

Answer (score 3):

I was able to figure out what the problem was;
I found, that the github repo is actually on 207.97.227.239, therefor my subnetmask was wrong. Changed the routing rule to 207.97.227.0/24, and the traffic started routing, but still failed. I additionally had the problem, that my lease of the dhcp on my wireless was outdated and the gateway had changed.. so a "dhclient3 wlan0" did the trick and now I'm happy like a pumpkin!

Comment: Since it turned out to be a very localized problem, you should consider closing the question. Otherwise, you could try to think about some additional potential value of this to other users and modify the question.